# How to have different implementation of same record type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I understand that to define different implementations for the same type we will need to use `newtype`

```
data Person = Person {
  name :: String
  , age :: Int
} deriving Show

class Describable a where describe :: a -> String

instance Describable Person where
  describe person = name person ++ " (" ++ show (age person) ++ ")" 

newtype AnotherPerson = AnotherPerson Person
```

However with the haskell problem of name clash between Records of the same field name

```
instance Describable AnotherPerson where
  describe person = name person ++ " - " ++ show (age person)

<interactive>:79:65: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Person’
                  with actual type ‘AnotherPerson’
    • In the first argument of ‘name’, namely ‘person’
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘name person’
      In the expression: name person ++ " - " ++ show (age person)
```

I tried using pragma `DuplicateRecordFields` but it does not help. How can we do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have any duplicate record fields here; the only record fields are `name` and `age` on the `Person` type. The `AnotherPerson` type is not a record, and it does not have record fields. `AnotherPerson` "wraps" a `Person` value; it does not "inherit" the fields from the `Person` type.

The `AnotherPerson` constructor has a (non-record) field of type `Person`. You can pattern match on `AnotherPerson` to get at the underlying `Person` value:

```
instance Describable AnotherPerson where
  describe (AnotherPerson person) =
    name person ++ " - " ++ show (age person)
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my understanding of `newtype`